# Is this a Generalized Linear Model?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, linear-regression

If  $Y_{i}$ is independently distributed as $N(\mu_i, \sigma^2)$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ and suppose $\mu_i=\beta_0 + \log(\beta_1+\beta_2 x_i)$. Is this a GLM?

So my train of thought was, if I separate it into separate cases of $\beta_0$ being known vs. unknown. But after that, I wouldn't even know how to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\beta_0$ is known, then just linearize the model, i.e., 
$$
\exp\{\mu_i - \beta_0 \}  = \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_i.
$$
If $\beta_0$ is unknown, then you can perform the following linearization
\begin{align}
\exp\{\mu_i\} &= \exp\{\beta_0\}\exp\{\ln(\beta_1 + \beta_2 x_i\}\\
              & = \beta_1\exp\{\beta_0\} + \exp\{\beta_0\}\beta_2x_i \\
              & = b_0+b_1x_i,
\end{align}
however you won't be able to obtain the estimators of $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$ and $\beta_0$. Hence, it is a good approach in a case that you are interested in prediction rather than inference.

Another approach, as your model is non-linear, is to use non-linear regression. In this case you will have to to provide some initial value for $\beta_0$ (initial values for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ can be obtained from a linear regression of the first aforementioned model once you'l provide some value for $\beta_0$).

Comment: Algebra wise, I one hundred percent understand everything you did. Logic-wise, not so much.

So for the known case, we basically just try to get a linear function on the right hand side to match what our normal link function right hand side looks like. 

For the unknown case, is it because we are now estimating the Betas, and when we move it in that form, we can say $b_0$ is the same as $\beta_{1}exp{\beta_{0}?$ I think that makes sense. But what constitutes it being a GLM or not. My instincts tell me the unknown case isn't and the other one is.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is missing?

Comment: Just made an edit to clarify!